# Shoreline change analysis in ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, arcgis-pro, raster-calculator, change-detection

I am trying to determine the change/reduction of shorelines using Sentinel 2 data using ArcGIS Pro 2.8. However, I don't have a lot of experience in raster analysis and I'm a bit at a loss... how would one approach this? I'd like to:

1. Select/filter pixels to only the shoreline.
2. Determine which pixels should be counted as "shore"/"land".
3. Apply the analysis to images from six-month intervals to determine change over time.

[image]

Comment: What is magnitude of changes you expect? How to account for tide? Is resolution of your blurry images even close to expected changes? If you don't have answers, it will be a waste of time, machine learning or manual digitizing.

Answer (score 2):

This would call for a classification analysis. You could perform a classification analysis to determine waterlines (water vs. ground) for each year. There is a Classify Pixels Using Deep Learning tool available in ArcGIS Pro.

Then you can compare the rasters from each year (probably using Raster Calculator) to detect change. Alternatively, you could convert the classified raster to a polygon in order to compare polygons.